How can a directory be tested for existance whe the folder contains foreign characters
I would like to know if it is possible to test the presence of a directory, when the folder contains foreign characters. I've been struggling with this and have not found a solution or came to a conclusion why this does not work when testing from inside batch files.
The funny thing is this only fails when testing with variables.
Has someone got any ideas?
Thanks!
Here is a sample of my batch file for analysis:
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
CLS
CHCP 65001
SET "Folder=%~1"
IF EXIST "C:\μTorrent Pro" ECHO Folder present & ::This line actually works
IF EXIST %Folder% ECHO Folder present & ::This line fails


Use the short name (dir /x)

@Magoo that might not be available. Windows has turned off generating short names by default for more than a decade, and even before that many people like myself already disabled generating short names for all partitions

@phuclv : Batch has traditionally maintained compatibility with prior versions, so I take the optional route and turn the shortname generation ON.

@Magoo that's a Windows feature and has nothing to do with batch. Once Windows has turned off then most users won't know to turn it on, and enabling it has some bad consequence like this

@phuclv : Swings and roundabouts. That bug will cause any existing batch using ~s to potentially fail. Those who don't know shouldn't be let loose on the prompt - pre- or post-change.

You have a typo. You need to use SET "Folder=%~0" to get the script's current file path. If you need the directory ("Folder") where the script is located in, use: SET "Folder=%~f0".
%0 is the script itself. The %1 is the first CLI argument. %2 the second and so on. The ~ removes quotes from the input. You should always use quotes on the CLI to handle spaces in path names. So if you run your script with my_batch.cmd "C:\μTorrent Pro\" that should work, too.
I was also able to run without CHCP 65001.
Additional: Use REM for comments. :: is just an empty label and not meant for that.

OK. According to rzickler answer, I came up with a theory that the problem wasn't in the script itself, but with the shell calling the batch file. What is happening is that the shell cannot pass names that do not comply with codepage 437. So, I cannot use the batch file without running into the situation described above. Anyway, I thank all of you who had spent time on trying to figure the problem and helping me out!

Did you try changing the codepage to 65001 before running the script? (aka by running it inside of the CMD after issuing a codepage change?)
